# Shiny deployment problem, hangs at: Uploading bundle for application: 413154

Tags: r, deployment, shiny

My shiny app works in my viewer but hangs when I deploy the app to `shinyapps.io`. In the files deployed to shinyapps.io are `global.R`, `app.R`, `app.Rproj` and `/data` (directory containing a subdirectory of 300 pdf files in total of about 800mb). I read the pdf data text and create a text analysis in `global.R`.

When trying to deploy all it does is

- something like: `preparing... DONE`
- Then it hangs forever on `Uploading bundle for application: 413154..`

```html
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] bindrcpp_0.2.2  DT_0.4          visdat_0.1.0    tidytext_0.1.8  broom_0.4.4     quanteda_1.3.4  tm_0.7-5       
 [8] NLP_0.1-11      pdftools_1.8    forcats_0.3.0   stringr_1.3.1   dplyr_0.7.6     purrr_0.2.5     readr_1.1.1    
[15] tidyr_0.8.1     tibble_1.4.2    ggplot2_3.0.0   tidyverse_1.2.1 shiny_1.1.0    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.17        lubridate_1.7.4     lattice_0.20-35     assertthat_0.2.0    digest_0.6.15       psych_1.8.4        
 [7] mime_0.5            slam_0.1-43         R6_2.2.2            cellranger_1.1.0    plyr_1.8.4          httr_1.3.1         
[13] pillar_1.2.2        rlang_0.2.0.9001    lazyeval_0.2.1      readxl_1.1.0        rstudioapi_0.7      data.table_1.10.4-3
[19] Matrix_1.2-14       labeling_0.3        foreign_0.8-70      htmlwidgets_1.2     munsell_0.4.3       janeaustenr_0.1.5  
[25] spacyr_0.9.91       compiler_3.4.3      httpuv_1.4.3        modelr_0.1.2        pkgconfig_2.0.1     mnormt_1.5-5       
[31] htmltools_0.3.6     tidyselect_0.2.4    crayon_1.3.4        withr_2.1.2         later_0.7.2         SnowballC_0.5.1    
[37] grid_3.4.3          nlme_3.1-137        jsonlite_1.5.9000   xtable_1.8-2        gtable_0.2.0        magrittr_1.5       
[43] tokenizers_0.2.1    scales_0.5.0.9000   RcppParallel_4.4.1  cli_1.0.0           stringi_1.2.4       reshape2_1.4.3     
[49] promises_1.0.1      xml2_1.2.0          stopwords_0.9.0     fastmatch_1.1-0     tools_3.4.3         glue_1.2.0         
[55] hms_0.4.2           rsconnect_0.8.8     parallel_3.4.3      yaml_2.2.0          colorspace_1.3-2    rvest_0.3.2        
[61] bindr_0.1.1         haven_1.1.1
```

If you need additional things to help me, feel free to ask! Any help much appreciated!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question per se, but it's likely that some storage format other than raw pdfs would be a better way to go. You could do the pdf extraction ahead of time and just store the text?

Answer (score 2):

It might seem elementary, but the problem is the size. I've deployed an app whose folder contained only a few KB's worth of files, and it took a pretty long time at the same `Uploading bundle for application: xxxxx`. Your app might also need a lot of libraries, as you have 19 loaded.